# Netsuite report or search of line item description strings

Tags: line, netsuite

I'm looking for the correct way to do a search or report in Netsuite that searches sales orders for a specific word in the line item descriptions. Our current, flawed, system involves putting **BACKORDERED** in the description of backordered items. We currently use a search for unfulfilled items to look for backorders, but this doesn't really work and is a terrible way to do it. There's got to be an easy way to search the line item descriptions of each sales order. Just searching item descriptions doesn't do it, because this is added after the item is put on the sales order. Netsuite doesn't seem to have the concept of line item descriptions in sales orders, but of course it must exist, as the description will stay whatever you set it to. What's the correct name for what I'm trying to search, and the syntax involved?

Comment: Hi VEIIERD, it would help to know your scrtucture, why don't you show us in code what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the problem was the name of the field that describes items in a sales order. It's apparently called "memo", despite it not being a memo line, and the main line having its own memo field for a different purpose. All is good now.

Answer (score 0):

In a transaction saved search, the line item description field is called "Memo". However, you probably want the "Item Fields..." "Back Ordered" field. It returns the real time Total quantity back ordered for the item.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Saved Search criteria]

You could achieve this by creating a transaction search where 
type = sales order
main line = false
item fields... description "contains" BACKORDERED.

Note: this will return all the item lines. You can control this further by making this a summary type report on the header fields